# How to tell Typescript that a return value will not be null based on whether or not the return value of another function isn't null?

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following:

```
const sockets = new Map<string, { socket: (...args: any[]) => void; isForegrounded: boolean }>();

sockets.set('1', { socket: { emit: () => undefined }, isForegrounded: true });
sockets.set('2', { socket: { emit: () => undefined }, isForegrounded: false });

const getSocket = (socketId: string) => sockets.get(socketId)?.socket ?? null;
const getIsForegroundedSocket = (socketId: string) =>
    sockets.get(socketId)?.isForegrounded ?? false;

const someFunction = () => {
    // do stuff

    const socketId = '1';
    const isForegroundedSocket = getIsForegroundedSocket(socketId);
    if (isForegroundedSocket) {
        const socket = getSocket(socketId);
        socket.emit('some-action', { hello: 'world' });
    }

    // do more stuff
};
```

This would throw an error,

```
socket.emit('some-action', { hello: 'world' });
^^^^^^ `socket` is possibly null
```

However, as you could tell above, if the return value of `getIsForegroundedSocket` is not null, then it'd be impossible for the return value of `getSocket` to be null for the same `socketId`.

How can I get Typescript to understand this? I'm trying to avoid doing the following:

```
socket!.emit('some-action', { hello: 'world' });
```

Comment: I believe that is due to the define being in an IF. Try using LET socket = NULL outside the IF and keep assignment of the value inside the IF.

Comment: Nope, same error: https://tsplay.dev/WKb6zm

Comment: Why not just use `socketInfo = socket.get(socketId)` then use verify that object and use `.isForegrounded` and `.socket` off of it after you know it's not `null`? The type system can't follow the reference that getting the same thing off a map twice with the same key would lead to the same result but even for a human it would take more time than if you make it absolutely explicit. Thus you'd get way clearer code for future maintainers *and* as a bonus the TS type checking would work correctly.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I ended up doing:) but conceptually I was wondering how one would achieve what I asked in the OP.

Comment: ① Is this a [mre]? Is `socket` a function or does it have an `emit` method? ② You want control flow analysis to pass through several function calls and variable assignments. I can maybe imagine a special subtype of `Map` where calling `get()` could narrow things (even though this is not safe unless you also track subsequent `set()` or `delete()` calls, see [ms/TS#13086](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086)) but not through so much indirection as shown here. I'd say the answer to this question is "it's either impossible or so convoluted to implement that I wouldn't trust it"